# What is the difference or separates O(log(n)) and O(n)?

Tags: java, big-o

This is the code I have been given but I cannot decide whether it is O(log(n)) or O(n).

```
int i=n;
while (i > 0) {  
   i/=2;  
}
```

Comment: This code cannot compile. Do you mean i/2 == 2 ?

Comment: Looks like homework.  How did you try to solve it?

Comment: yes, it is meant to be i/= 2 @MarounMaroun.

Comment: I believe it is log(n) because it is being divided by 2 at each step and not O(n) as its not from 0 to n

Comment: You probably wanted to write O(log(n)) and O(n).

Answer (score 5):

Lets assume `n = 1000`.

How many iteration it'll take until `i = 0`?

Each time you divide it by 2. So we'll get the following table:

```
Iteration |   i
----------|--------
    0     |  1000
    1     |  500
    2     |  250
   ...    |  ...
   ...    |  ...
    10    |   0  <-- Here we stop
```

Does this help you to figure out the complexity? (It should - Hint: What is ~log(1000) and what does O(n) mean?)